# 'ENOENT, open' when using connect-multiparty param 'uploadDir' (Express 4)

Tags: node.js, angularjs, file-upload, express, multipart

I am using connect-multiparty with Express4/Node/Angular. Running it locally, on a file upload, I get a 'ENOENT open' error when I specify an 'uploadDir', but it works with the default multipart().

> Error: ENOENT, open 'upload_image_dir/83785-xjohos.png' POST
>   /api/providers/me/543695a47be1540000a4fedc/upload/image 400 20ms - 63b

code: (built on top of generator-angular-fullstack)
    var config = require('../../config/environment');
    var multipart = require('connect-multiparty');
    var router = express.Router();

```
// ... more routes

router.post('/me/:id/upload/image', auth.isAuthenticated(), multipart({ uploadDir: './upload_image_dir' }), controller.upload_image);
```

Where am I going wrong?

Old posts refer to problems due to BodyParser, but that is not so with express 4 and latest connect-multiparty.

If the error means 'no directory exists', then do I need to manually create the dir? the examples and documentation dont mention it.

Should I be using relative paths like ive used above?

EDIT 1:
I tried the following and still the same error:

```
router.post('/me/:id/upload/image', auth.isAuthenticated(), multipart({ uploadDir: __dirname + '../../../upload_image_dir' }), controller.upload_image);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__dirname` does not add a `/` to the end.

Change this:

```
__dirname + '../../../upload_image_dir'
```

to this:

```
__dirname + '/../../../upload_image_dir'
```